# Rails 3 unexpected JSON behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, activerecord

Models

```
class Project
 has_many :tasks

class Task
 belongs_to :project
```

`Task` has the following attributes (among others)

```
t.string project
t.integer project_id
```

This is code I inherited and I'm not sure why it has both columns but I noticed an unexpected behavior with this setup. When I render JSON for `@task`, it included the `project` info as such (may not be properly formatted JSON but you get the idea)

```
{
  "task": {
    "duration": 3,
    "project": {
      "project": {
        "id": 9,
        "description": "Roofing,
        "updated_at": "2011-09-07T16:58:34Z",
        ...
      }
    },
    "project_id": 9,
    ...
  }
}
```

I checked `project` column in the database and it's nil. Seems like Rails treated that column like a relation call (I can see why even) instead of just a column, is that intended behavior?

Comment: What is `project` column (type string)? I see you have the foreign key `project_id` though, that looks correct.

Comment: Yes, as indicated above, `project` column is of type `string`.

Comment: Sorry, unclear, I meant "What is the project column?", what data is stored in it? I was saying (type string) to differentiate it from `project_id` of type integer. Clearly `project` is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct in your assumption of a naming collision. You can actually access your task's project like that (`task.project`), so when the rails JSON renderer renders `task.project` it pulls down the JSON rendition of its relation like you're speculating. I recommend you change the name of that column to not clash with rails' convention, or you can change the name of the relation if you would rather not change the database column (look at the [`:class_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) option), but it may cause more confusion down the road. I just read that you inherited that code. Usually when you specify model relations, you automatically get attributes such as `project_id`, and a helper method `project` which accesses the task's project. Perhaps the author of the code was not aware of this and felt the need to create those two columns himself. It might be okay to keep `project_id`, but the `project` attribute is clearly clashing.

Alternatively, you can override the JSON rendition yourself by defining a method in your model with the signature `def as_json(options={})` which returns a hash representing your desired JSON rendition, ex. `{ :name => task.name, :project => something_else }`.

Comment: Yeah, I was right about the name clash, I consulted the original developer (he was new to Rails) and ensured there was no real use for `project` column and I deleted it, now it no longer pulls the related `project` info.